# Amigos si me podrían orientar como hacer este ejercicio: llenar una matriz con la siguiente serie:0,2,3,2,5,5,7,10,12 por favor! Diagrama de flujo

Tags: matrices

Se le agradecera su ayuda, ya que soy nueva en estos temas de programación y es para entenderlo mejor

Comment: y qué has intentado?

Comment: No esperas que hagamos toda tu tarea verdad? Ni siquiera pones el lenguaje en el que lo vas a desarrollar..

Comment: Cris Carmona realizarlo mediante iteraciónes, pero lastimosamente me sale error

Comment: Mira [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad. También deberías, aprovechar y hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Jorge Luis, No solo quiero ver en que estoy fallando ya  que los estoy mediante iteraciónes y solo es diagrama de flujo ya que recién me estoy adentrado en estos temas gracias. :)

Comment: Hola @Jhoana bienvenida a StackOverflow!! Te sugiero que sigas el consejo de J.Rodriguez te ayudará mucho en futuras preguntas, luego de eso puedes crear una nueva pregunta con todo lo que hayas investigado, intentado, etc y con gusto te ayudaremos

Comment: Las preguntas pidiendo ayuda con tarea escolar deben incluir el enunciado del problema, un resumen del trabajo realizado hasta el momento y una descripción de los problemas/dificultades que se estén encontrando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El diagrama no se, pero la secuencia es: el primer mas segundo numero te dan el 4 numero, lo mismo con los demas numeros